# Given, $a,b,c,d,e$ are real numbers such that $2a^2<5b$. Show that $x^5+ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e$ cannot have all real roots.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, polynomials, quadratic-forms, positive-definite

> Given, $a,b,c,d,e$ are real numbers.
>    $2a^2<5b$. 
>   Show that $$f(x)=x^5+ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e$$ cannot have all real roots.

Comment: If you don't say a little what have you tried... we could consider that you want your homework to be done without efforts...

Comment: @JeanMarie Sorry for the wrong question. I hope the edit will help make things clear.

Answer (score 3):

I think this [the originally posted [problem statement with $f(x)=ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e$](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/1911930/4)] is an incorrect copying of the problem with a monic polynomial written as $x^n + ax^{n-1} + bx^{n-2} + ...$ (for $n=5$).  There is no inequality or any other condition on the two highest degree coefficients that could limit the number of real roots but there are such inequalities on $a$ and $b$.

The question for degree $n$ monic polynomials is, what linear inequalities have to hold between $a^2 = (\sum a_i)^2$ and $b = \sum a_i a_j$ for real numbers $a_1, a_2, \dots a_n$.

All roads, such as Cauchy-Schwarz or expanding $\sum (a_i - a_j)^2$, seem to lead to the same inequality $(n-1) a^2 \geq 2n b$.  I suspect that all other inequalities on $(a,b)$ can be deduced from that.

For $n=4$ the condition for real roots is $3a^2 \geq 8b$.

For $n=5$ the condition for real roots is $2a^2 \geq 5b$.

Therefore, I guess that your problem was actually to

> show that $x^5 + ax^4 + bx^3 + cx^2 + dx + e$ cannot have all real roots if $2a^2 < 5b$.

Knowing what the inequality should be for degree $n$ monic polynomials, it can also be proved by induction on $n$ , differentiating the polynomial and using Rolle's theorem,  that it is a condition for the polynomial to have at most $n-2$ real roots.

Comment: It now becomes evident, as would have said Sherlock Holmes ! A very fine and well explained deduction work [+1].

Answer (score 1):

The claim is false.  $x^4-(1/4)x^3=0$ with $2a^2=2, 5b=-1.25$ has all real roots.

Comment: Maybe the OP has forgotten to say that the coefficients $a,b,c,d,e$ are $>0$ ?

Comment: Still false, can use +(1/4) in place of -(1/4).

Comment: But in this case, you take c=d=e=0. As soon as c,d,e are $>0$,  even very small, for example with $1x^4+(1/4)x^3+(0.001)x^2+(0.001)x+(0.001)$, some roots become non-real. My hypothesis about supplementary condition $a,b,c,d,e>0$ is based on rather extensive simulations.

Comment: Nevertheless, as the OP doesn't want 1) to say what he/she has attempted, 2) to, at least, react to the domain of validity of his/her question, it is not worth the value to help him/her...

Comment: Then edit the question.  Then test it with $15x^4+60x^3+90x^2+60x+15=0$.

Comment: I won't dare to do that. It's up to the OP to do it.

Comment: You are right. My assumption was not the good one...

Comment: I understand why I hadn't found such a counterexample: the coefficients I was taking in my simulations were of the form 10*rand ... I will know it for next time...

Comment: @JeanMarie, I think we can infer what the problem must have been.  See other answer.